# Node.js and socket.io, Clients not sharing counter

Tags: javascript, node.js, scope, socket.io

I'm playing around with node.js and socket.io, trying to get a counting program working.  Basically what it should so is increase a shared counter by 1 each time a connected client presses a button, and display that number to all connected clients.

What I'm getting is each client has a separate counter somehow.  For example if I count to 10 on one client, then go and start counting on another, it starts at 1.  The first client will then resume from 10 if I go back.  Ive tried to troubleshoot this as best I can, but I'm not too savvy when it comes to JS scoping issues (which I suspect this is) or sockets.

```
var socketio = require('socket.io');
var io;
var count = 1;

exports.listen = function(server){
    io = socketio.listen(server);
    io.set('log level', 1);

    io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket){
        joinRoom(socket, 'Lobby');
        count = handleCounter(socket, count);
    });
};

function handleCounter(socket, count){
    socket.on('endCount', function(){
        io.sockets.emit('endCount', {
            success: true,
            num: count
        });
            count++;
            console.log(count);
    });
    return count;
}

function joinRoom(socket, room){
    socket.join(room);
}
```

As a note, I had it working before when I simply placed the code from handleCounter into the `io.sockets.on('connection')` function, but I'd like to know why it wont work when I try to place it outside like the code above.

Any help is really appreciated, thanks.

Comment: This the effect you're looking for? http://realtimeanswer-5042.usw1.actionbox.io:3000/

Comment: Yeah! for the most part that's what I'm trying to get to happen.

Comment: The source is all there http://realtimeanswer-5042.usw1.actionbox.io:3000/server.js http://realtimeanswer-5042.usw1.actionbox.io:3000/package.json etc . . . I'm still working on a socket.io version

Comment: Thanks, I'll check that out.  Although I am still curious as to why my code isn't acting properly though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are returning `count` at the end of `handleCounter()`, but it's incremented in an asynchronous function, so it hasn't been incremented before it returns.

Instead of passing `count` around, you can just refer to the `count` variable you declare at the top of the file, which is available in all of your closures.  You also don't need the `endCount` listener, and emitter, if all you want to do is send out the new count to the clients every time a client connects.

```
var socketio = require('socket.io');
var io;
var count = 1;

exports.listen = function(server){
    io = socketio.listen(server);
    io.set('log level', 1);

    io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket){
        joinRoom(socket, 'Lobby');
        handleCounter();
    });
};

function handleCounter(){
    count++;
    console.log(count);

    io.sockets.emit('count', {
        success: true,
        num: count
    });
}

function joinRoom(socket, room){
    socket.join(room);
}
```

Comment: That works, I guess I was trying to over-complicate things by passing around `count`.  I actually had thought of just referring to the `count` variable normally, but I always get worried that I'm not doing things the "correct" way and go off on coding tangents.  Thanks. (Also I'm upping the counter on button press on the client side, so that's what I'm was using the endCount emitter and listener for)

Answer (score 0):

http://realtimeanswer-5042.usw1.actionbox.io:4000/

in short, send the data on connect and send the data to all the clients on button click.

The client only updates the dom when it gets a message from the server.

The biggest issue I see in your code is that you're complicating the scope of count.  it's module scope, and can simply be used without passing it around.

server:

```
var app = require('express')()
  , server = require('http').createServer(app)
  , io = require('socket.io').listen(server)
  , count = 0;

var port = 4000;

server.listen(port);

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.sendfile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

io.set('log level', 1);

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
  console.log(count);
  socket.emit('count', count);
  socket.on('inc', function () {
    count++;
    console.log('inc', count);
    io.sockets.emit('count', count);
  });
});
```

client

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset='utf-8'>
<title>real time fun</title>
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>

<script>
  $(function() {
    var socket = io.connect();

    socket.on('count', function (count) {
      $('#count').text(count);
    });

    $('button').click(function () {
      socket.emit('inc');
    });
  });
</script>
<div id='count'></div>
<button>inc</button>
```